# try to get monthly report of donation and expenses of charity organization

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables called expenses and donation

Table 1

expenses

```
s.no   expensedate    expense
1       13/01/16         30
2       15/01/16         60
```

Table 2

```
s.no   donationdate    donation
15       14/01/16         30
18       19/01/16         10
```

Out Put required

```
Month       Expense    Donation
Jan            90            40
```

I can get the output individually   like

```
Month  expense
jan       90
```

or

```
Month  donation
jan       40
```

but cannot join them together,  such a way it could give required output.

thx

Comment: You should show the queries that get the individual results.

Comment: please post you code it will be useful to recognize your quesiton

Comment: SELECT
SUM(Donation) AS donation,
Monthname(DonationDate) AS Month
FROM donation
WHERE month(DonationDate) = month(CURRENT_DATE())

Comment: 40     May    this is the output of the query

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using `union all` and `group by`:

```
select date_format(dte, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm,
       coalesce(sum(expense), 0) as expenses,
       coalesce(sum(donation), 0) as donations
from ((select expensedate as dte, expense, null as donation
       from expenses
      ) union all
      (select donationdate as dte, null, donation
       from donations
      )
     ) ed
group by date_format(dte, '%Y-%m')
order by yyyymm;
```